# Which of the following are in R(T), when R(T) is the range of t.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T: P2→P3 be the linear transformation given by the formula:

T(p(x)) = xp(x)

Which of the following are in R(T)?

**a)**  x+x^2
**b)**  1+x
**c)**  3-x^2

I just need some clarification on whether I'm doing this correctly. If I'm not doing this correctly, then please explain the process I need to take. For example, I think the problem is solved the following way:

a) T(x+x^2) = x(x+x^2) = x^2+x^3. If I divide this by x, I get x+x^2 - so does this mean that this is in R(T)?

b) T(1+x) = x(1+x) = x+x^2. If I divide this by x, I get 1+x, so I'm thinking this is in R(T).

c) T(3-x^2) = x(3-x^2) = 3x-x^3, when divided by x is equal to 3-x^2, so I think this is in R(T).

Comment: It is difficult to read the math. You can learn to format math on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Daryl - thank you. I've looked at the site and tried to format using the ^ and _ for subscripts and superscripts, but nothing that I try works. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $x+x^2$ is in the range of $T$, you need to find a polynomial $p(x)$ in $P_2$ such that $T(p(x))=x+x^2$. Since $x+x^2=x(1+x)$, you can take $p(x)=1+x$: that’s certainly in $P_2$, and $T(1+x)=x(1+x)=x+x^2$.

Note that $T(p(x))$ **always** has a factor of $x$, so every polynomial in the range of $T$ must be divisible by $x$. That should help you finish off the question in short order.

Comment: So, would this be correct:

a) x(p(x)) = x+x^2 --> p(x) = 1+x
b) x(p(x)) = 1+x --> p(x) = (1/x)+1
c) x(p(x)) = 3-x^2 --> p(x) = (3/x)-x

Would this process always give me the answer I need? That is, by setting my T(p(x)) equal to the function being tested - and solving for p(x).

Comment: The first one is right, $x+x^2$ is in the range. The others are not right, since your $q(x)$ are **not** polynomials. For example, $\frac{1}{x}+1$ is not a polynomial. Thus $x+1$ is not in the range. Neither is the third one.  The polynomials that are in the range are the polynomials with $0$ constant term. When you multiply any polynomial $q(x)$ by $x$, there is no constant term in the answer.

Comment: @Cee: The process is right, in the sense that dividing the polynomial by $x$ gives you the only possible ‘source’, but you’re overlooking something very important: the domain of $T$ is $P_2$, so if you don’t get something in $P_2$ when you divide by $x$, your polynomial isn’t in the range of $T$. In particular, a polynomial with a non-zero constant term is **never** $x$ times some polynomial, so it’s never in the range of $T$. This immediately rules out $1+x$ and $3-x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

A polynomial (vector) $q(x)$ is in the range of $T$ if and only if there **exists** a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $T(p(x))=q(x)$, that is, $q(x)=xp(x)$.

That is probably enough information to enable you to handle the rest on your own.

Comment: Definition is in title. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed that, and removed first sentence.

Comment: Would a be p(x) = x+x^2, b be p(x) = (1/x)+1, c be p(x) = (3/x)-x.
This would mean a-c are in R(T), right?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. A polynomial in $P_2$ is $a+bx+cx^2$ for some $a,b,c\in{\mathbb R}$. What happens when you transform this polynomial?
2. You are given the polynomial $q$ and you need to find if there exists a $p$ which satisfies $q=T(p)$. For instance, you need to find $p$ such that $T(p)=x+x^2$. Then verify that $p\in P_2$, to show if $x+x^2$ is in the range of $T$.

Comment: Unfortunately, for this one, it came just a bit late. Also, I think your hint 2 is  slightly incorrect: you are not given $T(p)$, you are given $q$ and you are asked whether $q=T(p)$ for some $p\in P_2$. You can't say that b) and c) are given $T(p)$'s, in particular.

Comment: @julien I will correct the terminology. What you described is what the intention is, but it doesn't appear to be as clear as I thought.